# using external PCLs with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library, xamarin.forms

I've this Xamarin Forms solution that creates 4 projects as we all know.

App(portable)

App.Droid

App.iOS

App.WinPhone

Apart from this I've added 2 more projects to the solution

App.Service

is the azure mobile service, this is not directly used in any of the projects above but via Table Controllers (Web API stuff)

Here is the most tricky part. In order to be able to use the same azure mobile service & write more clients on top of it, I created a new PCL project

App.Shared (PCL)

This has all my model classes & a wrapper on top of the azure APIs. The idea was to use this PCL as a reusable lib that I could use on any other clients on a future day.

Now my App project uses this App.Shared as a direct project reference. This works all fine as long as I am in debug mode.

But as soon as the app goes into release mode, or is deployed on the device, I loose everything that's defined under that App.Shared PCL library.

Seems like something related to Linking of libraries?

Any pointers what I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: What I have seen a couple of people do, is creating an instance of the object in the platform start up code (where it does `LoadApplication`).  And by direct project reference, do you mean `right click -> add reference --> solution --> then selected App.Shared`?

Comment: Yes correct on your view of direct reference. Since both projects are residing in same solution, I just right click on references, select projects node & select app.shared project from the list.

Comment: I can't create an instance of the object in my native apps as this Library does not show up there, even adding the using statements is throwing compilation issues.

Comment: after debugging further. I found out, it's not the App.Shared project that is causing the issues. It's building fine in release mode too & I can access the methods in it while debugging the android app deployed on device. 
The problem is in Azure Mobile services project. For some reason the calls to the APIs in this App.service projects are failing on android. I've the mobile services component added & the component is initiated in MainActivity. 
Any call to it always returns with an Unauthorized response.

Comment: Interesting, are all your keys setup correctly?

Comment: If you are asking about the azure service Key, then no. I am deploying the azure service locally.
At this point, the backend is not ready to be deployed live & needs work on it. Thus deploying it locally & I can confirm it's accessible from the browser app on mobile device & simulator.